# VBA - provider cannot be found with accdb format

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

With the below code i get the following error when ran provider cannot be found, The below code is copied and edited from the net, It previously used .mdb files but I tried to change it to .accdb because thats the format I need it in. I'm trying to make a macro that when ran copies certain cells into a database, adding to it.

I get this error

```
 run-time error "3706"
 Provider cannot be found it may not be properly installed
```

-

```
Const TARGET_DB = "testdb.accdb"

Sub AlterOneRecord()
   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim fld As ADODB.Field
   Dim MyConn
   Dim lngRow As Long
   Dim lngID As String
   Dim j As Long
   Dim sSQL As String

   'determine the ID of the current record and define the SQL statement
   lngRow = ActiveCell.Row
   lngID = Cells(lngRow, 1).Value

   sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblPopulation WHERE PopID = " & lngID

   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
   MyConn = ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB

   With cnn
     .Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
     .Open MyConn
   End With

   Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
   rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
   rst.Open Source:=sSQL, _
            ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
            CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, _
            LockType:=adLockOptimistic

   'Load contents of modified record from Excel to Access.
   'do not load the ID again.
   For j = 2 To 7
      rst(Cells(1, j).Value) = Cells(lngRow, j).Value
   Next j
   rst.Update

   ' Close the connection
   rst.Close
   cnn.Close
   Set rst = Nothing
   Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is there an easier way to do this? or should I try and fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is complete connection string to your data base file.

[(More about connection string)](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

I give you a rough idea which usually works with my code:

remove this line in your code:

<strike>`.Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"`</strike>

instead use this one:

```
.ConnectionString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
```

or you could use this one instead:

```
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
```

For further information you could see [this w3schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_connection.asp).

Comment: It seems to be getting past that bit now, thanks! more problems though with this code 'sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblPopulation WHERE PopID = " & lngID'